# Way to automatically change fragments after delay

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app begins with a FragmentA. I want FragmentA to appear for like 5 seconds then display another FragmentB replacing FragmentA.

I have displayed FragmentA by:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentA  frag = new FragmentA();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();       
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fl,frag); 

        ft.commit();
```

Not sure what to do after this.

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: *quick solution please* : LOL

Comment: @2Dee not funny, help tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially call the

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl, new FragmentA())
            .commit();
```

and after that, add this:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
             //Second fragment after 5 seconds appears
             getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.fl, new FragmentB())
                 .commit();
          }
    };

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

**Update: Just remove the runnable from Handler to prevent the runnable from executing after the activity is destroyed.**

```
@Override
   public void onDestroy () {
     handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: If the user presses the button back and the 5 seconds has not passed the app crash

Answer (score 3):

If you need to run some code after delay, use Handler.
Example:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        hideFragmentA();
        showFragmentB();
      }
    }, 5000)
```

Where 5000 - delay in milliseconds

Comment: sorry no animation on FragmentA. I want it to display for a few then display the next fragment

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code snippet for the fragment replacement:

```
FragmentB fragmentB= new FragmentB();
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fl, fragmentB)
            .commit();
```

If you need to do the fragment replacement after 5 seconds, just schedule an event/task for 5 seconds and when time is elapsed just do required replacement.